# NamError: name 'get_wsgi_application' is not defined

Tags: python, django

When I run:

```
python manage.py runserver
```

The following error occurs:

> `NamError: name 'get_wsgi_application' is not defined`

My `wsgi.py` file is:

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE","coding.settings")
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application=get_wsgi_appication()
```

Comment: `NamError` and `get_wsgi_appication` are both typos. I formatted your post for you, but there's no question here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It reports `NameError` rather than `ImportError`, means you have successfully imported the function `get_wsgi_application`, but maybe called something wrong.

after check your code, I think:

```
application=get_wsgi_appication()
```

should be:

```
application=get_wsgi_application()
```

considering you miss spelled `NameError` as `NamError`, maybe the real error report is:

```
NameError: name 'get_wsgi_appication' is not defined
```

Comment: Welcome @user3500741 , and if you could accept this answer by click the `√` under votedown button, I would be more appreciated.

Comment: As i am new to stackoverflow , i don't know it but i click on it.

Comment: : ) you will soon get used to here